# Jquery .off() to unbind the previous event handler is not working

Tags: jquery

There are multiple select html tag in one page,and I would like get two values of previous value and new value from the same list after user click the dropdown list. It seems like has a bug with .off() , but I don't know how to find it out.

https://jsfiddle.net/etozr53s/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.SizeSelect').on('click', function() {

    var sel = $(this);
    sel.data("preValue", sel.val());
    sel.off('change').on('change', function() {
      var th = $(this);
      th.data("newValue", th.val());

      //output
      $('#log').append('pre:' + th.data("preValue") + ' / select:' + th.data("newValue") + '<br/>');

    });
  });
});
```

```html
   
<select id="SizeSelect_14" class="SizeSelect" name="SizeSelectName">
  <option value="5">N/A3</option>
  <option value="101">N/A2</option>
  <option value="105">N/A1</option>
</select>

<select id="SizeSelect_15" class="SizeSelect" name="SizeSelectName">
  <option value="6">2N/A3</option>
  <option value="102">2N/A2</option>
  <option value="106">2N/A1</option>
</select>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: you want to get previous value and new value from the same list (after change)??

Comment: yes, I would like to get two values

Comment: You register a onclick event, but you remove a onchange event. they are different event. change all onclick to onchange

Comment: try using 'one' instead of 'on'. Then you do not have to clean up. It will only fire once.

Comment: @FraserCrosbie if .use one(),it only normail on first click

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @FraserCrosbie https://jsfiddle.net/etozr53s/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this the code you want

> This code will output the previous selected value and the new
>   selected value **(from the same list)**)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.SizeSelect').on('change', function() {
      var th = $(this);
      var prevValue = th.find('option[data-prevValue]').attr('value');
      var newValue = th.find('option:selected').data("newValue", th.val()).attr('value');
      //output
      $('#log').append('prev:' + prevValue + ' / select:' + newValue + '<br/>');
      th.find('option').removeAttr('data-prevValue').removeAttr('data-newValue');
      th.find('option:selected').attr("data-prevValue", th.val());
    });
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/mt8haa7w/2/)